# Spring Application with Jakarta Bean Validation framework

Tags: spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I Wanted to create normal spring application (not spring boot or spring mvc) which uses Jakarta Bean Validation framework

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Tried to use above dependency but unable perform method/constructor argument validation using @NotNull @NotBlank etc.
Example

```
    public TestConstructor(@NotNull @NotBlank final String param1, @NotNull @NotBlank final String param2, @NotNull @NotBlank final String param3) {
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
    public void testMethod(@NotNull @NotBlank final String param1) {
        ...
    }
```

I created the below bean and was only able to validate objects manually

```
    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure().buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }
```

I wanted to perform auto validation of arguments and objects using jakarta bean validation framework (not with javax validation)

Comment: Jakarta isn't supported, so this won't work. You need the javax version. Which means `hibernate-validator` in the 6.x range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with this issue too. So i just copied required parts of Spring framework and create my own ValidatorBean with B&W, but actually with only validation.

```
 @Bean(name = "mvcValidator")
    public JakartaValidator validatorFactory(AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
        Validator validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
                .constraintValidatorFactory(new JakartaConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
                .buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        return new JakartaValidator(validator);
    }


public class JakartaConstraintValidatorFactory implements ConstraintValidatorFactory {
    private final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JakartaConstraintValidatorFactory(AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
        this.autowireCapableBeanFactory = autowireCapableBeanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key) {
        return autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?, ?> instance) {
        autowireCapableBeanFactory.destroyBean(instance);
    }
}


public class JakartaValidator implements Validator {

    private static final Set<String> internalAnnotationAttributes = new HashSet<>(4);

    static {
        internalAnnotationAttributes.add("message");
        internalAnnotationAttributes.add("groups");
        internalAnnotationAttributes.add("payload");
    }

    private final jakarta.validation.Validator validator;

    public JakartaValidator(jakarta.validation.Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        processConstraintViolations(validator.validate(target), errors);
    }

    protected void processConstraintViolations(Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations, Errors errors) {
        for (ConstraintViolation<Object> violation : violations) {
            String field = determineField(violation);
            FieldError fieldError = errors.getFieldError(field);
            if (fieldError == null || !fieldError.isBindingFailure()) {
                try {
                    ConstraintDescriptor<?> cd = violation.getConstraintDescriptor();
                    String errorCode = determineErrorCode(cd);
                    Object[] errorArgs = getArgumentsForConstraint(errors.getObjectName(), field, cd);
                    if (errors instanceof BindingResult) {
                        // Can do custom FieldError registration with invalid value from ConstraintViolation,
                        // as necessary for Hibernate Validator compatibility (non-indexed set path in field)
                        BindingResult bindingResult = (BindingResult) errors;
                        String nestedField = bindingResult.getNestedPath() + field;
                        if (nestedField.isEmpty()) {
                            String[] errorCodes = bindingResult.resolveMessageCodes(errorCode);
                            ObjectError error = new ViolationObjectError(
                                    errors.getObjectName(), errorCodes, errorArgs, violation, this);
                            bindingResult.addError(error);
                        } else {
                            Object rejectedValue = getRejectedValue(field, violation, bindingResult);
                            String[] errorCodes = bindingResult.resolveMessageCodes(errorCode, field);
                            FieldError error = new ViolationFieldError(errors.getObjectName(), nestedField,
                                    rejectedValue, errorCodes, errorArgs, violation, this);
                            bindingResult.addError(error);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // got no BindingResult - can only do standard rejectValue call
                        // with automatic extraction of the current field value
                        errors.rejectValue(field, errorCode, errorArgs, violation.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (NotReadablePropertyException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("JSR-303 validated property '" + field +
                            "' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - " +
                            "check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    protected Object getRejectedValue(String field, ConstraintViolation<Object> violation, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        Object invalidValue = violation.getInvalidValue();
        if (field != null && !field.isEmpty() && !field.contains("[]") &&
                (invalidValue == violation.getLeafBean() || field.contains("[") || field.contains("."))) {
            // Possibly a bean constraint with property path: retrieve the actual property value.
            // However, explicitly avoid this for "address[]" style paths that we can't handle.
            invalidValue = bindingResult.getRawFieldValue(field);
        }
        return invalidValue;
    }

    protected String determineField(ConstraintViolation<Object> violation) {
        Path path = violation.getPropertyPath();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Path.Node node : path) {
            if (node.isInIterable()) {
                sb.append('[');
                Object index = node.getIndex();
                if (index == null) {
                    index = node.getKey();
                }
                if (index != null) {
                    sb.append(index);
                }
                sb.append(']');
            }
            String name = node.getName();
            if (name != null && node.getKind() == ElementKind.PROPERTY && !name.startsWith("<")) {
                if (!first) {
                    sb.append('.');
                }
                first = false;
                sb.append(name);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected String determineErrorCode(ConstraintDescriptor<?> descriptor) {
        return descriptor.getAnnotation().annotationType().getSimpleName();
    }

    protected Object[] getArgumentsForConstraint(String objectName, String field, ConstraintDescriptor<?> descriptor) {
        List<Object> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
        arguments.add(getResolvableField(objectName, field));
        // Using a TreeMap for alphabetical ordering of attribute names
        Map<String, Object> attributesToExpose = new TreeMap<>();
        descriptor.getAttributes().forEach((attributeName, attributeValue) -> {
            if (!internalAnnotationAttributes.contains(attributeName)) {
                if (attributeValue instanceof String) {
                    attributeValue = new ResolvableAttribute(attributeValue.toString());
                }
                attributesToExpose.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
            }
        });
        arguments.addAll(attributesToExpose.values());
        return arguments.toArray();
    }

    protected MessageSourceResolvable getResolvableField(String objectName, String field) {
        String[] codes = {objectName + Errors.NESTED_PATH_SEPARATOR + field, field};
        return new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable(codes, field);
    }

    protected boolean requiresMessageFormat(ConstraintViolation<?> violation) {
        return containsSpringStylePlaceholder(violation.getMessage());
    }

    private static boolean containsSpringStylePlaceholder(@Nullable String message) {
        return (message != null && message.contains("{0}"));
    }

    private static class ResolvableAttribute implements MessageSourceResolvable, Serializable {

        private final String resolvableString;

        public ResolvableAttribute(String resolvableString) {
            this.resolvableString = resolvableString;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getCodes() {
            return new String[]{this.resolvableString};
        }

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public Object[] getArguments() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDefaultMessage() {
            return this.resolvableString;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.resolvableString;
        }
    }

    private static class ViolationObjectError extends ObjectError implements Serializable {

        @Nullable
        private final transient JakartaValidator adapter;

        @Nullable
        private final transient ConstraintViolation<?> violation;

        public ViolationObjectError(String objectName, String[] codes, Object[] arguments,
                                    ConstraintViolation<?> violation, JakartaValidator adapter) {

            super(objectName, codes, arguments, violation.getMessage());
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.violation = violation;
            wrap(violation);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRenderDefaultMessage() {
            return (this.adapter != null && this.violation != null ?
                    this.adapter.requiresMessageFormat(this.violation) :
                    containsSpringStylePlaceholder(getDefaultMessage()));
        }
    }

    private static class ViolationFieldError extends FieldError implements Serializable {

        @Nullable
        private final transient JakartaValidator adapter;

        @Nullable
        private final transient ConstraintViolation<?> violation;

        public ViolationFieldError(String objectName, String field, @Nullable Object rejectedValue, String[] codes,
                                   Object[] arguments, ConstraintViolation<?> violation, JakartaValidator adapter) {

            super(objectName, field, rejectedValue, false, codes, arguments, violation.getMessage());
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.violation = violation;
            wrap(violation);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRenderDefaultMessage() {
            return (this.adapter != null && this.violation != null ?
                    this.adapter.requiresMessageFormat(this.violation) :
                    containsSpringStylePlaceholder(getDefaultMessage()));
        }
    }

}
```